# CSS columns work on FF, break on Chrome, IE10

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10, multiple-columns

I'm having trouble with the layout changing dramatically when viewing the same page between different browsers.

In Firefox, the page renders beautifully, just as I need it to. Screenshot below:

[image: Page rendering in Firefox. The page displays two forms in two columns, with the left column half the width of the right column.]

In Chrome, it doesn't respect the column layout at all.

[image: Page rendering in Chrome. The form from the right column is spread across both columns, and the inputs are not all in order. It's all jenked.]

The form from the right is all up on the left column, its text area is on the second column, and I think the buttons are on the third column.

HTML is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XMLSVC Upload Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="blahblah/thisPage.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blahblah/thisPage.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="col1">
            <p>Use these forms to upload XML files into the study </p><br/>
            <form id="multipartUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <fieldset>
                   <legend>multipart/form-data</legend>
                   <label for="mpUsername">Username:</label>
                   <input type="text" name="username" id="mpUsername" /><br/>
                   <label for="mpPassword">Password:</label>
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="mpPassword" /><br/>
                   <label for="mpXmlData">XML File:</label>
                   <input type="file" name="xmlData" it="mpXmlData" /><br/>
                   <input id="submitMultipart" type="button" value="Submit" onClick="uploadMultipart();"/><br/>
               </fieldset>
            </form>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Output</legend>
            <div id="patientUploadDIV"></div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <form id="xmlUpload" >
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</legend>
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br/>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br/>
                    <label for="xmlData">XML File:</label>
                    <textarea id="xmlData" rows="50" cols="100" name="xmlData"></textarea><br/>
                    <input id="submitUpload" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadPatient();"/>
                    <input id="submitStringMultipart" type="button" value="Submit Multipart/Form-Data" onclick="uploadStringMultipart();"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS is here:

```
main {
   -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
   column-count: 3;
}
div .col1 {
   -webkit-column-span: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   column-span: 1;
}
div .col2 {
   -webkit-column-span: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   column-span: 2;
}

input[type="button"] {
   margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Bonus Question: What could I do to make this render properly in IE10? It's not crucial; this is just an internal page to test that a servlet is accepting data properly under all possible conditions. But I have no idea whether the tester will be working in IE10 or Chrome, and can safely assume they *won't* be using Firefox.

Comment: use display: table or flex, it will make it much easier for you

Comment: display: flex works okay, yeah. Thanks for the heads up. I'm hoping there's someone who knows how to rock multi-columns though, as display:flex kinda pinches the forms together and squishes the left one.